# Python - find first dictionary key in template

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I'm trying to show my dictionary keys and values in template in for loop, but I don't want to show the first key.
What is the best way to do it?
I thought of using something like

```
dictionary.keys()[0]
```

but i can't do it in template.
or maybe add counter to the for loop (not sure how to do it in the loop below)
This is my loop to show the dictionary-

```
 {% for year, durations in durationDict.items %}
      <optgroup label={{ year }}>
      {% for duration in durations %}
           <option data-from-date="{{ duration.from_date }}" data-to-date="{{ duration.to_date }}" value={{ duration.duration_id }}>{{ duration.from_date }}
                                - {{ duration.to_date }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What do you mean `first dictionary key`? Python dictionary is a hash table and it's not sorted, so there's no order for keys.

Comment: I create the dictionary in a way where the first key that I add is the latest year and I don't want to show it in the optgroup label. all other years (keys) should be shown.

Comment: In the past I've done something like this: `durationDict.items.0`

Comment: There's no "first key" in a dictionary. The fact that you could do `dict.keys()[0]` could give you surprisingly different result if the same code is run on different machines. It could work perfectly on your local machine and not in production, it may work today but not tomorrow. If you want sequence, use a list of tuples.

Comment: Maybe you want to learn what a hash table looks like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: As @ShangWang points out, python's dicts don't preserve order -- if you use one of the other suggestions, you might get the wrong key omitted. The [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#module-collections) standard library includes an OrderedDict class which will do what you want.

Comment: I hear what you're saying about the order. If I use orderedDict - how will I get the first key on template then?

Comment: @user2880391 check my answer

Comment: I think it's impossible to answer your question without knowing whether you want to exclude the first _key_ (order irrelevant) or the first _year_ (order relevant). If you simply want to exclude the first key, maybe @bozdoz's answer will suffice but if you want to exclude the first year, you probably want to sort your keys in a list or tuple first using `sorted`, `sort`, `map`, `lambda` or a combination of these. Alternatively, if you want to sort based on insertion order rather than the numerical value of your keys, use an `OrderedDict` as previously suggested.

Comment: or `pop` a specific year to remove it: dict.pop(2010, '')

Comment: @bozdoz - durationDict.items.0 returns key + value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I finally done was as following:

creating an OrderedDict out of my Dictionary, making sure that it's sorted by dates Descending:

```
 duration_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(duration_dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=True))
```

So now I can be sure that the first key is also the latest year.
and for presenting all the key,value pairs without the first year I used forloop.first, as suggested by @bozdoz:

```
{% for year, durations in duration_dict.items %}
                            {% if not forloop.first %}
                            <optgroup label={{ year }}>
                            {% endif %}
                           {% for duration in durations %}
                              <option data-from-date="{{ duration.from_date }}" data-to-date="{{ duration.to_date }}" value={{ duration.duration_id }}>{{ duration.from_date }}
                                - {{ duration.to_date }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to show the first iteration of a for loop in a Django template, you can omit it by checking for [forloop.first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

```
 {% for year, durations in durationDict.items %}
      {% if not forloop.first %}
      <optgroup label={{ year }}>
      {% for duration in durations %}
           <option data-from-date="{{ duration.from_date }}" data-to-date="{{ duration.to_date }}" value={{ duration.duration_id }}>{{ duration.from_date }}
                                - {{ duration.to_date }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `filter` tag. For example:

**template_tags.py**

```
from django import template


register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def exclude_first(dict):
    first_key = list(dict)[0]
    del dict[first_key]
    return dict
```

**html**

```
{% load template_tags %}

{% for year, durations in durationDict|exclude_first %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

This should allow you to loop through all of the items in `durationDict` **except** for the first item. Keep in mind that `dicts` are not ordered by default. If you have a custom key/value pair that you want deleted every time, you can simply replace `del dict[first_key]` with `del dict['latest_year']` (or replace `latest_year` with the key name you want to delete).

Comment: Keep in mind, a dict is not ordered so you can't predict which key will be deleted with this method.

Comment: Fair enough, I just wrote this assuming he is using an `ordered_dict()` or something along those lines

Comment: I also edited my answer to show OP how to delete the `latest_year` key (or any specific key/value), assuming that ultimately that is his goal.